# How do I make this drop down list touch friendly

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to make this list touch friendly with javascript or CSS. How do I do it?

When searching on google I get a different version of drop down (the one at the head of the page,and how to make that touch friendly

```
<select class="form-control" name="dob_month">
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_date" class="form-control">
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
    <option value="05">5</option>
    <option value="06">6</option>
    <option value="07">7</option>
    <option value="08">8</option>
    <option value="09">9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>31</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_year" class="form-control">
    <option value='1985'>1985</option>
    <option value='1986'>1986</option>
    <option value='1987'>1987</option>
    <option value='1988'>1988</option>
    <option value='1989'>1989</option>
    <option selected value='1990'>1990</option>
    <option value='1991'>1991</option>
    <option value='1992'>1992</option>
    <option value='1993'>1993</option>
    <option value='1994'>1994</option>
    <option value='1995'>1995</option>
    <option value='1996'>1996</option>
    <option value='1997'>1997</option>
    <option value='1998'>1998</option>
    <option value='1999'>1999</option>
    <option value='2000'>2000</option>
    <option value='2001'>2001</option>
    <option value='2002'>2002</option>
    <option value='2003'>2003</option>
    <option value='2004'>2004</option>
    <option value='2005'>2005</option>
</select>
```

I am using it to collect date of birth details of a user on a website

Comment: What is "touch friendly" in your eyes??

Comment: mobile browser have different way to show select/option than a computer. it will be something like this: http://imgur.com/HHinokQ not normal css dropdown menu.

Comment: There's no way you can style a `select`-tag. Because of that, you need to find an alternative. Instead of a dropdown, you can put them into `ul`- and `li`-tags. You're better off using something else than `select`. Go ahead and Google: `ul li select option alternative` and you will see :)

Answer (score 0):

Find a [date picker widget](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date) that is compliant with mobile browsers and delegate to the native `<input type=date>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make drop down lists touch friendly. Mobile browsers have their own interface for letting their users select an option from a drop down list. You can style the select field, but the option list is different for each browser.